# Error "Cannot call toString on undefined" but variable is defined

Tags: javascript, undefined, tostring, typeerror

In this piece of Javascript

```
creds = cp[0];
data[creds.toString()] = cp[1]; // data is an object
```

Chrome gives me the error `TypeError: Cannot call method toString of undefined` on the second line. However, I've verified via the debugger that the value of `creds` is at that point the number `1400`.

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be very cautious when using `for in` loop to array. Use normal loop instead.

The array `cpl` has not just data but functions, so third `cp` in the loop is function. That's why `creds` turned to undefined.

This link has good explanation: [Why is using "for...in" with array iteration a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays)

Comment: That's new info. Why cautious?

Comment: +1 Within the for loop your hitting a `cpl[i]` thats a method name  ., e.g `cpl["copy"]`.  That sets `cp` to that methods toString() (so the string `function (start,length) ...`) which causes `creds` to be `undefined` after `creds = cp[0];` so the subsequent `creds.toString();` fails.

Comment: @Alex K @Sangdol Thanks for the explanation. I already knew that somewhere, but didn't think of it when I wrote the loop. Turns out that this is indeed the problem and I debugged it wrongly (inspected the value in the first iteration only, while the error is in a later one)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript don't need variable type so do it by removing `toString()`.

btw I'm not sure you can call `toString()` on a primitive type as `int`

Comment: `data` is an object, not an array, so I convert `creds` to a string to act as key. If it's not needed, it at least makes the intent clearer.

Comment: You should have specified this before.  
Anyway calling `toString()` on an Integer (if it is) will stop the Javascript. Have you already tried w/o it?

Comment: you can have it data['' + creeds + ''] (those are two single quotes as in string start string end) It will cast your number to a string

Comment: Literal numbers don't any methods (to avoid decimal point confusion)  but `var a=[1234] .. a[0].toString()` is perfectly fine

Comment: @Alex K Actually in another question I saw expressions like `100..toString()` and `100["toString"]()`